# Combination for applicant pool

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The qualified applicant pool for six management trainee position consists of seven women and five men. 
How many different groups of applicants consisting of at most two women can be selected for the position?

The answer I have obtained is 8 possible groups due to the following logic:

6C6 +7C6

6C6 represents 5 men and 1 women being chosen for the positions 
7C6 represents 5 men and 2 women being chosen for the positions
Thou I am doubting this is the right answer please correct me

Comment: nCk is the number of ways to choose k applicants from a pool of n applicants. In this context, what do you mean by 6C6 and 7C6?

Comment: Pour idea to separate in groups of one woman and two women is good. But the rest is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose no women, you have to choose 6 men and there aren't enough so you can't choose no women.

If you choose one woman, you have to choose all 5 men.  There are 7 ways to chose 1 woman and only 1 way to choose all 5 men so there are 7 ways to do this.

If you choose 2 women there are $7\choose2$ ways to do this.  That's $7\times\frac62 = 21$.  You must chose four men.  There are ${5\choose4} = 5$ ways to do this.  So there are $21\times5 = 105$ ways to do this.

In total there are $105 + 7 = 112$ ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

7C6 is not correct, since you only need 4 men not 5 men to be chosen when there are 2 women being chosen already~

Comment: 8 is not the correct answer. For 6C6=$7\choose 1$, and for 7C6 (note there  are only 6 position for these people so you cannot have 7~)=$7\choose 2$x5.